# how to submit an html form without browser automatically and periodically?

Tags: javascript, bash, authentication, web

My ISP ask me to submit my user/pass in a web page each time i connect to Internet. also it has a maximum logon timeout (about 10 hours) that kick me out and ask me to login again. I need a command prompt script/batchfile for Windows and Linux that automatically submit my account information without the need of opening web browser.

the following html code is the source code of the login page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>EE> login</title>
</head>
<body>
<input name="username" type="text" value="username"/></td>
<input name="password" type="password" value="passwordtext"/></td>
<input type="submit" value="OK" /></td>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  document.login.username.focus();
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to send a POST request with the appropriate fields filled. You can do it in 2 lines of Python (or similar). Have you any specific difficulty? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am not asking for code, i just need an approach that help me to write my own code.

Comment: is any way that i can used windows scripting or linux bash commands? I am not much familiar with python. however if there is no way I would appreciate if you make an answer based on python and get up vote.

Comment: If you use linux, you can use `curl` to POST the username and password.

Comment: would you give an example with curl please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example from [cURL Tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#POST):

```
curl --data "birthyear=1905&press=%20OK%20"  http://www.example.com/when.cgi
```